# Assigning a value to cell depending of another cell list of item value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Here is the situation: I have column `I` with the header as "Design" and column `J` with the header as "DETAIL", then I have column `K` with a header as "TYPE_W". OK on this last column `K`, I selected from  cell  `K2`  up to `K22` and added a data validation Criteria: `LIST OF ITEMS` then `DETAIL,DESIGN,OTHER`, so what I want to accomplish is:

If I select on `K2` "DESIGN", I want in cell `I2` the value `=Y`, if DESIGN is not selected, then I want the value to be empty on `I2`, so the same thing for cell J2 if value selected in `K2` is "DETAIL", then I need on `J2` A VALUE `=Y` otherwise then I need an empty value, so of course I want this for all the cells under `I` and `J` that a value in `K` has been selected if nothing is selected is because in that row there is not data imputed, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- paste in **`I2`** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K2:K="DESIGN"; "Y"; ))
  ```
- paste in **`J2`** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K2:K="DETAIL"; "Y"; ))
  ```

  [image: 0]
- **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jo9jKtjyw_rqoRiMnQYeZ2z4m1LRZa1cQFdPyTgTejc/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it is working but why in the cell  I2 and J2 it is just displayed the formula you gave me, sorry i am new on this so i am trying to learn, the rest of the cell are showing as you show me  in your sheet but cells I2 and J2 just show the formula and i don't see how to refresh it , why does not show a the rest of the other cells as Y or EMPTY ? THANKS A LOT

Comment: sorry to ask another question, i am trying to get all the rows from the sheet and then i download the sheet as xls file, in order to later insert then into a visual foxpro dbf table, so what i want is the next time i want to fill again this google sheet is to delete the values in there as i will need to download again different data, so the question is if i delete the existing rows, it also will delete the formula you gave me and the column that as the list of items ? thanks again

Comment: let me see if can make insert a picture here , look on I2 and J2 it shows the formula instead of the value

Comment: ?how can i insert a picture here to show you